# How to debug a CMake target that needs root privileges with vscode

Tags: c++, cmake, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a CMake target that needs root privileges on vscode, but when I replaced my gdb executable with a script to launch it using sudo, vscode won't start the debugger anymore.

This was my attempt to make gdb run with sudo:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh
sudo gdb-orig $@' >/usr/sbin/gdb
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/sbin/gdb
```

I don't get any error on vscode, it just won't start debugging my executable. Also, I can run the script without any problems from the terminal.
What am I missing? Is there any alternative to debug targets that need root privileges?

Comment: Quick and dirty hack is to use `setuid` on `gdb` executable assuming it is owned by root. Of course, this is rather large security risk which allows any user to launch a process as root through `gdb`.

Comment: @Quimby thanks, that really did the trick. I think I just need to remember to undo that on gdb when I'm done with this project, and it will be fine.